# Flush mmaped file with APR

Tags: file-io, apr

I use APR library to write large amount of data. Everything works OK, but now I want to create checkpoints during write, where my data is consistent. I want to implement it by writing some data to the mmap-ed file followed by flush.

I can't figure out how to do this with APR. I open file with `apr_file_open`, then I create mapping using corresponding function in APR. After that I write data to mmap-ed region and than call `apr_file_flush` with file handle that I've passed to `apr_mmap_create` but it returns immediately. I think that flush is relatively heavy operation but I can't see any significant difference in performance with or without flush. Am I doing it wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I need to call `msync` function (from sys/mmap.h header) in this case. Flush wouldn't work.